# newline in text area in html form doesn't remain once posted

Tags: html, textarea, newline

I'm having a textarea in my contact form with php mail function. In php mail i have set the header to html.

But even if the user types like this

```
Line1....
Line2....
```

I'm getting in mail like this.

```
Line1....Line2....
```

What could be the reason?

**Update:**
The text area is as simple as this.

```
<textarea id ="msg" name="message" cols="" rows="5" class="msg">Message</textarea>
```

Its posted to this script with jquery ajax function

```
<?php
$sub =  "Message Posted";
$email = "some@somewhere.com";
$message = "<b>Message :</b><br/>" . $_REQUEST["msg"];
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ifthi@ifthi.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '. $_REQUEST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


// Send
mail($email, $sub, $message,$headers);
?>
```

But when getting in email all are in a single line. Even if you write in 2 line and submit.

Comment: The answer is probably "A new line in HTML source code is treated like any other bit of white space, use appropriate elements or stop using HTML formatted email (as its very hard to do right)" … but since there is no code at all for us to look at, its rather hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you set your mail to HTML you should replace all line breaks with HTML 
 Tags.

I think the PHP function you need is:
[string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//whatever you want to replace new lines with
$newLineCode = "<br/>";
$message = $_POST['myTextArea'] ; //unadulterad text we got via Post
$modifiedTextAreaText = ereg_replace( "\n", $newLineCode, $message);
echo " Result of Code Snippet " . $modifiedTextAreaText ;
?>
```